# How do you use Google Chrome Webstore app tester accounts?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have an App that I am building and I want testers. I saw the tester 
accounts option but cannot seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just was able to figure it out. You add people as testers. Publish the App to your tester accounts. Give the testers the link to the app. They have to log into the webstore. Then go to the link and they can install it.